# The normal brush in sculpt mode on Blender doesn't work

Tags: sculpting

I use a mac and would like to know if there is any way to fix this?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What about it is not working? DO any of the other brushes work?

Answer (score 5):

Sculpting requires some geometry to deform if you try to use the default brush on a cube nothing will happen.

You could subdivide the cube <kbd>W</kbd> *Subdivide* in *Edit Mode* or press the *Enable Dynamic* button in the topology section.

[image]

The effect is shown in the image right a subdivided cube, front left dynamic topology.