# Cannot sculpt, created head from Plane

Tags: modeling, sculpting, subdivision-surface, multiresolution

I know this question had already been asked.

[The normal brush in sculpt mode on Blender doesn't work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8200/the-normal-brush-in-sculpt-mode-on-blender-doesnt-work)

But that didn't help.

It's my first blender model, but i already sculpted the body, boots, gloves and other stuff without problems.

Here's the mesh+topology I try to sculpt 
[image]

After switching to sculpt mode it looks like this, with a multi-res of 2
[image]
However, if i try to sculpt it, no matter what brush, nothing happens. Even with strength at 1.0 using the flatten tool, or using the Mask tool.

Applying a solodify didn't help.
Neither did deleting the multi res, duplicating the mesh and reapplying the multi-res.
Nor using subdivision first and then a multi-res.

I tried using Alt+C "Mesh from Curve/..." and still no success with sculpting.

After enableing dynotopo and trying to sculpt, a switch back to edit-mode showed new vertices. But no changes to the actual 3D form in Sculpt/obejct/edit mode. Only new vertices.

I always tried both my wacom tablet and my mouse.

I can still sculpt the character, boots and other stuff (hidden, but listed in the outliner) in the same Scene. These are created from a cube and not planes though.

What am I doing wrong? It should be possible to sculpt from a plane, I looked it up in tutorials and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have figured it out myself.

In object mode i applied rotation & scale with Ctrl+A.

afterwards it worked fine, sorry for troubeling you guys